# configuring apache 2.2 for php5.2/5.3 module on Win Server 2008

Tags: php, windows-server-2008, apache2.2

I'm trying to configure apache 2.2 for php 5.2 (or preferably 5.3, but php.net seems to say not to) on Windows Server 2008.

C:\Apache2.2\
C:\php\v5.2\

Apache is running fine before I add this to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/v5.2/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:/php/v5.2/"
```

Then apache spits out this error when I try to restart it from cmd:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 129 of httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/php/v5.2/php5apache2_2.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.
```

It's definitely there!

I googled the error and found a lot of people complaining of it, but they're all for mistakes like referencing `php5apache2.dll` instead of `php5apache2_2.dll`.

EDIT: btw, when I use the installer, and it modifies httpd.conf for me, I still get the cannot find error during start up. wtf…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the LoadModule […] has to go at the very end of httpd.conf. dunno why, but i moved it, and apache stopped complaining.